# Issue accessing Auctex environments

Tags: environments, auctex

I recently installed AucTex on a new computer, and am having an issue that I do not recall with regards to accessing environments. Using C-c C-e, auto-complete etc., I am only able to access a handful of environments. Auctex does not detect align, matrix, or any other math environments. It is possible to simply enter the environments by hand, or create custom environments, but this seems tedious for something that I wouldn't expect to be happening. Perhaps there is something I am missing.

Comment: Does your document load a package like `amsmath`? In a regular document without that package, AUCTeX does not autocomplete the `align` environment for me; but if `amsmath` is loaded and the buffer has been parsed, then `align` is an option listed for `C-c C-e`.

Comment: It does load the package, and I am able to insert the environments manually without a problem. However, it is not detected. Used packages include amsmath,amsthm,amssymb, and a few other math based ones.

Comment: Try closing the buffer with the packages loaded via the usual `\usepackage`, then reopening it. Then try `C-c C-e` again.

Comment: Instead of closing/opening, you can use the revert-buffer command

Comment: @RomainPicot -- Yes! That's what I couldn't remember. OP: save file first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It unfortunately did not end up working. I assume it is probably some issue with my emacs build.

Comment: @zalba19 - Do you have `(setq TeX-parse-self t)` in your init-file?  If not, put it in your init-file, restart emacs and open your file again.  Another try would be hitting `C-c C-n` while your file is open and see if `align` environment is offered in the completion list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an unspecified issue in the init file, solved in an unspecified way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue; turns out the issue was in my init-file. Turns out there a mistake in the file and when it was corrected, everything ended up working correctly. Thanks for the help